# Is it possible to join these MySQL tables Attendee and Message?

Tags: php, mysql

So i have got these two MySQL tables. I am trying to join the two statements to find out which **TelNumber** the **senderNo** is associated with:

[image]

[image]

I have tried this query but it only returns the messages that have a associated attendee, not ones that dont have an associated **telNumber** registered on the database.

```
SELECT Attendee.`ownerName`, Attendee.`businessName`,Messages.`messageID`, Messages.`senderNo`, Messages.`messageContent`,Messages.`timestamp`,Messages.`type`,Messages.`viewed` 
FROM Messages 
INNER JOIN Attendee ON Messages.`senderNo`= Attendee.`telNumber` OR Attendee.emailAddress
```

The or equals part is because **senderNo** can also contain and Email address in which the type would be **Email**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The INNER JOIN ends with `OR Attendee.emailAddress`.  What is emailAddress supposed to be comparing with?

Comment: Looks like your "OR" is doing `(senderNo = telNumber) OR (emailAddress)`

Comment: comparing with the same senderNo, probably not the best thing to be doing

Answer (score 1):

1. The structure of your query is incorrect. After the OR, it should be

   Messages.senderNo = Attendee.emailAddress
2. To get the messages that don't have an associated telNumber, you need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `OR` to compare one column to two columns like that, you need to do both comparisons separately and join them with `OR`.

```
ON Messages.senderNo = Attendee.telNumber OR Messages.senderNo = Attendee.emailAddress
```

You can also use `IN` to compare a value to multiple things:

```
ON Messages.senderNo IN (Attendee.telNumber, Attendee.emailAddress)
```

To get messages that don't have a matching attendee, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: How would i get all responses from this messages table even if a message received does not match an attendee in the attendee table?
The problem i am getting is if a message received is from an unknown sender wont show because that sender wont be in the attendees table.
How would i do it so i get all responses ?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to include messages that don't have a match.

Comment: Thats works! is there a way to change the owner name and business name to say unknown instead of NULL ?

Comment: `IFNULL(ownerName, "Unknown")`